# Extracting Sub-string Between Two Characters in String in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column containing strings that are comprised of different words but always have a similar structure structure. E.g.:

```
2cm off ORDER AGAIN (191 1141)
```

I want to extract the sub-string that starts after the second space and ends at the space before the opening bracket/parenthesis. So in this example I want to extract ORDER AGAIN.

Is this possible?

Comment: `r"2cm off ORDER AGAIN (191 1141)".split(r"(")[0].split(" ", maxsplit=2)[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["out"] = df["col"].str.extract(r'^\w+ \w+ (.*?)(?: \(|$)')
```

Note that this answer is robust even if the string doesn't have a `(...)` term at the end.

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WErMgk/1) showing that the regex logic is working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
r"2cm off ORDER AGAIN (191 1141)".split(r"(")[0].split(" ", maxsplit=2)[-1].strip()
#Out[3]: 'ORDER AGAIN'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern of data is similar to what you have posted then I think the below code snippet should work for you:

```
import re
data = "2cm off ORDER AGAIN (191 1141)"

extr = re.match(r".*?\s.*?\s(.*)\s\(.*", data)       
if extr:
    print (extr.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
s = '2cm off ORDER AGAIN (191 1141)'
second_space = s.find(' ', s.find(' ') + 1)
openparenthesis = s.find('(')
substring = s[second_space : openparenthesis]
print(substring) #ORDER AGAIN
```